# VB.NET mshtml library causing "Access is denied" (0x80070005) Or "Object reference not set..." errors

Tags: vb.net, mshtml

I am using the mshtml library inside a VB.NET console application to extract some data from an http request.

The code is as follows:

```
Dim htmlDocument As IHTMLDocument2
For i As Integer = 0 To 10
    searchHtml = getHtml(url)
    htmlDocument = New HTMLDocumentClass()
    htmlDocument.write(searchHtml)
    htmlDocument.close()
    Dim results As IHTMLElement = htmlDocument.body.all.item("ires")
    For Each li As IHTMLElement In results.all.tags("li")
        Dim element As IHTMLElement = li.all.tags("cite")(0)
        If element.innerText.ToLower().Contains(text) Then
            ' Do Something here
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The code above is called recursively from another method.

I can run my code in debug and it works time after time with no problem.

If I compile the exe and run it then I receive one of two errors. Initially I got an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" after 11 calls to the above. This is repeatable and always occurs after 11 iterations.

If I add a Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) before the above and re-compile I get the "Access is denied" error, again after a certain number of iterations.

Comment: Use the HTML Agility Pack instead.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Pretty undiagnosable behavior.  Start by putting [STAThread] on your main method.  Consider an occasional call to GC.Collect() next.

Comment: It is pretty un-diagnosable behaviour....quite annoying really! Good shout on the garbage collector but I think I'm going to take a look at the HTML Agility Pack first. It sounds like it is a lot nicer to use than the mshtml library.

Comment: HTML Agility Pack is excellent; much easier to work with (love the XPath support) and I'm no longer getting the error. Thanks for the heads up SLaks. If you answer as such I'll mark it.